# crossdomain javascript user verification

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have a functioning cross domain Javascript plugin but so far has no user verification.

i would like to add that using two parameter:

1. user_id
2. url

I know ajax is probably not the right solution (given security limitations) what would be the best approach to do that.

thank you.

Comment: You might want to give a bit more information on your concrete problem. It is hard to undertand what does work, what not, and what you want to achieve with what tools.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking - is this a question about cross domain 'ajax' calls, or verifying a user with javascript?

If it is a question about cross domain javascript, there are many different ways of accomplishing it with out using any actual ajax, such as the 'iframe' method.

A quick google can turn out tutorials on doing this.

If you are asking a question on verifying a user with javascript, I am assuming you have access  to a backend, just create an AJAX call with the required values as parameters.

Comment: I am not aware of the iframe approach but will google it. thanks. I do have access to the backend of course but wouldn't it be problematic to make ajax call from the user site back to mine?

Comment: Google analytics does it without an iframe either, so there has to be a way.

Comment: salmane, there are other methods as well - I am not sure of them. I have never needed to make a cross-domain call.

I did read somewhere, and this is quite sketchy in my mind, that you can send headers (if the user is on a new version of FF) that can change restrictions - or something like that. I am sorry I can not really give you much more information on that.

Comment: Shane, after much googling and thinking, i figured my solution to be a combination of a dynamically generated javascript ( the one installed cross domain) which generates an iframe. it seems like google analytics does create an iframe but i am guessing they destroy it after it serves its purpose cause i don't seem to find it in the DOM. Thanks for your help